# How to use gmail SMTP in ASP.NET form

Tags: asp.net, forms, syntax, smtp, gmail

I am a ASP novice and am troubleshooting a form for work. None of us here are ASP experts as we use PHP. But I am on the bottom of PHP experience as well, mostly working with HTML/CSS alone. My current forms credentials look like:

```
rotected Sub SubmitForm_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If Not Page.IsValid Then Exit Sub

        Dim SendResultsTo As String = "email to"
        Dim smtpMailServer As String = "email server"
        Dim smtpUsername As String = "email username"
        Dim smtpPassword As String = "password"
        Dim MailSubject As String = "Form Results"
```

How would I go about making this form send to a Gmail address? I know I must include the port (587) somewhere, but cannot figure out where, as this form doesn't match the syntax of any other forms I have seen. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
protected void SendMail()
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            try
            {
                msg.Subject = "Add Subject";
                msg.Body = "Add Email Body Part";
                msg.From = new MailAddress("Valid Email Address");
                msg.To.Add("Valid Email Address");
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                System.Net.NetworkCredential basicauthenticationinfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Valid Email Address", "Password");
                client.Port = int.Parse("587");
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = basicauthenticationinfo;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.Send(msg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Gmail/Google will block it from sending the email. You can change the settings from sender's gmail account to allow "less secure apps" to access it.

Answer (score 16):

You can add this in your `web.config` file

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="yourMailId@gmail.com ">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" defaultCredentials="false"
      port="587" userName ="yourmail@gmail.com" password="yourpassword" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
   </system.net>
```

Comment: Would I remove the entire portion from my existing code?
    
    `Dim SendResultsTo As String = "email to"
    Dim smtpMailServer As String = "email server"
    Dim smtpUsername As String = "email username"
    Dim smtpPassword As String = "password"
    Dim MailSubject As String = "Form Results"`

Comment: you will not need to specify the username password and network again in the code, in your code create a SmtpClient object to send the message

Answer (score 1):

Create a System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient object, set the SMTP server info you are using.

Then create a System.Smtl.MailMessage with the message data and send it:

```
using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mail = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()) {
    using (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("from*where.com", "to@where.com") {
        IsBodyHtml = true,
        Subject = "Subject text",
        Body = messageBody,
    }) {
        mail.Send(message);
} // using
```

You can configure your SmtpClient in the constructor, we use web.comfig, so I don't have that code.

Comment: I have no idea  how to go about doing that, hahaha. I shouldn't even be working on this project, but unfortunately I am the only one available to do it.

Comment: The web.config in the above answer sets up the SmtpClient object, so you can send a message using my code unchanged.

Comment: Here is my full syntax http://pastebin.com/85Ad9swq

I apologize, but I don't even know where to start. I  have no viable reason to learn ASP.NET...aside from this one instance -_-

Answer (score 1):

Google now blocks sign-ins from an app (even over SSL) to send an email. You have two options:

1. Enable less-secure apps for the account you are using; OR
2. Generate an app-password from Google (recommended)

For option 2, you will have to enable 2-factor authentication before you can generate an app pasword. 
Here are the steps I took to get this working on my ASP.NET web app

[How to configure an ASP.NET web app with Gmail SMTP](https://blog.nicolaayan.com/2018/01/configuring-an-asp-net-web-app-with-gsuite-gmail-smtp/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Dim client As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient
client.UseDefaultCredentials = False
client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender@gmail.com", "password")
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
client.Port = 587
client.EnableSsl = True
client.Send("sender@gmail.com","reciever@gmail.com","subject","body")
```

Comment: I get a runtime error.

    If Not Page.IsValid Then Exit Sub

    Dim client As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    client.Credentials = Net
    System.Net.NetworkCredential("ajtroxell67@gmail.com", "pajax6767")
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    client.Port = 587
    client.EnableSsl = True
    client.Send("sender@gmail.com","ajtroxell67@gmail.com","subject","body")

            Try
                Dim txtQ As TextBox = Me.FormContent.FindControl("TextBoxQ")`

Comment: please delete this. your password is revealed!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 2-step verification, don't forget to generate an application specific password and use that, not the password you use to log on to Gmail.

(Sorry I can't add this as a comment. Not enough rep at the time of posting this.)

Answer (score -1):

There's [no shortage of tutorials](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx) on how to send an email from within .NET.

Essentially you want a `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` object to interact with the SMTP server, a `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` object to hold the message data, and configuration data in your config file to direct the client on how/where to send the message.