# getting exception while sending mail

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, smtp, html-email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use gmail SMTP in ASP.NET form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982810/how-to-use-gmail-smtp-in-asp-net-form)

getting exception while sending mail. -The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. Need solution.
My Code is :

```
public bool mailSender(string toMailId, string uniqueGuid)
        {
            try
            {
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                string linkForConfirm = "orderConfirmation.aspx?id=" + uniqueGuid;
                string Subject = "Shiv Cart Grocery Shop Confirmation";
                string body = " <div style='width:700px; margin:0 auto;'><div style='background-color:#800000; width:700px'>";
                body += "</div><div><h2>Shiv Cart Grocery Shop</h2><h3 style='color:#0099FF; width:700px'> Click Below To Confirm Your Order</h3>";
                body += "<a href='" + linkForConfirm+ "' id='a' ></a></div></div>";
                MailAddress fromMailAddress = new MailAddress("mail@sumedhasoftech.com", "Shiv Cart");
                MailAddress toMailAddress = new MailAddress(toMailId);
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(fromMailAddress, toMailAddress);
                mail.Subject = Subject;
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailSenderUserName"].ToString(), WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailSenderPass"].ToString());
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                smtpClient.Send(mail);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: so you're trying just to use gmail.com as an open relay?

Comment: I guess you are missing: smtpClient.SmtpPort = 25;

Comment: Please look at this which might help you **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982810/how-to-use-gmail-smtp-in-asp-net-form/7982891#7982891**

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you should add this for gmail.

```
smtpClient.SmtpPort = 587;
```

And further information can be found in this thread: [How to use gmail SMTP in ASP.NET form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982810/how-to-use-gmail-smtp-in-asp-net-form/7982891#7982891)