# Sending email via asp.net webpage

Tags: asp.net, web

I particularly made this tutorial as a basis: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/371417/Send-Mail-Contact-Form-using-ASP-NET-and-Csharp

I successfully debug the errors but then it doesn't seem to work... HELP please...

**PREVIEW:**

[image: my contact us form]

CODE BEHIND:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
```

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

`}
protected void SendMail()
{
    // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
    var fromAddress = "ml27.santos@gmail.com";
    // any address where the email will be sending
    var toAddress = YourEmail.Text.ToString();
    //Password of your gmail address
    const string fromPassword = "Password";
    // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
    string subject = YourSubject.Text.ToString();
    string body = "From: " + YourName.Text + "\n";
    body += "Email: " + YourEmail.Text + "\n";
    body += "Subject: " + YourSubject.Text + "\n";
    body += "Question: \n" + Comments.Text + "\n";
    // smtp settings
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
    }
    // Passing values to smtp object
    smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //here on button click what will done 
        SendMail();
        DisplayMessage.Text = "Message sent!";
        DisplayMessage.Visible = true;
        YourSubject.Text = "";
        YourEmail.Text = "";
        YourName.Text = "";
        Comments.Text = "";
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}}`

Comment: You need to provide more details about WHAT doesn't work and WHAT errors you encounter

Comment: which error occured and where..

Comment: no mail is being sent...

Comment: Please look [How to use gmail SMTP in ASP.NET form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982810/how-to-use-gmail-smtp-in-asp-net-form/7982891#7982891)

Answer (score 0):

I think Gmail SMTP port should be 465, not 587.

https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en&from=75726&rd=1#ts=1665018,1665142

Comment: I use 587 successfully, but it is Google...

    var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    {
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("acct@gmail.com", "pw"),
                        EnableSsl = true
    };

Comment: Log in to your account and check Sent folder. It the `smtp.Send` method doesn't throw an exception it means that the connection is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried commenting on that article / contact the author?

I guess there are 2 things here:

A. You haven't done anything in catch block. You should consider following in catch block

```
catch(Exception ex){
DisplayMessage.Text = ex.Message;
DisplayMessage.Visible = true;
}
```

B. check if the gmail account you are using has smtp with pop3/imap enabled.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    protected void SendMail()
    {
        // any address where the email will be sending
        var toAddress = YourEmail.Text.ToString();
        //Password of your gmail address
        const string fromPassword = "Password";
        // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
        string subject = YourSubject.Text.ToString();
        string body = "From: " + YourName.Text + "\n";
        body += "Email: " + YourEmail.Text + "\n";
        body += "Subject: " + YourSubject.Text + "\n";
        body += "Question: \n" + Comments.Text + "\n";

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("ml27.santos@gmail.com");
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtpClient.Port = 587;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ml27.santos@gmail.com", fromPassword);
        message.From = fromAddress;
        message.To.Add(toAddress);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        message.Body = body;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
```