# Sending link to Email from desktop application

Tags: c#

I have a desktop app, which has log in/signup/and forgot password..The email which he registers on app is his personal Email..For example,his personal email is abc@gmail.com, which he also registers on this desktop app and now has forgotten the password for app..I want to send a link to his email to reset password for app..
This is my code:

```
private void forgotPwdLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email = txtLoginID.Text;//(1)I get emailId from textbox
        var ac = new AccountController();
        var user = ac.FetchUserbyEmail(email);//(2)based on email I retrieve his details
        string UserName = user.UserName;
//(3)Check if there is password for that email,if yes,proceed..If no password, the emailid could  be wrong           
if (user.UserPassword != null)
        {
            using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", txtLoginID.Text))
//sender@gmail.com here could me my desktop app
//txtLoginID.Text here is email for which link is to be sent 
            {
                mm.Subject = "Resetting Password";
                mm.Body += "Please click the following link to activate your account" + "<br    />aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";//sending some junk to see if I can actually send succesfully
                mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential(UserName, "<password>");
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Send(mm);
            }
        }
```

Is this the right way to do so?..Answers are appreciated and thanks...

Comment: You know you can just create a gmail account and check if it works, right?

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I have another issue again-"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required"..I get this SmtpException on the last line of the code- smtp.Send(mm); So I can't see if my code is right..

Comment: Check this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982810/how-to-use-gmail-smtp-in-asp-net-form